# prevent return null when variable does not exists at firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a pojo that has a set of values

```
data class Product(val productId:String = "",val name:String = "", val image:String = "", val price: Int = 0, val hasDiscount:Boolean = false)
```

At firebase, I load my product sometimes with hasDiscount and sometimes I dont set that attribute to a product in which I'm specting the default hasDiscount value as false, so when I get my data from Firestore, I get null for this field and then my list of products does not return and my list is not populated

```
suspend fun getProductList(shopId:String):Resource<MutableList<Product>>{
        val productList = mutableListOf<Product>()
        val snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("shops").document(shopId).collection("products").orderBy("hasDiscount",
            Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().await()
        for(product in snapshot){
            val produdctId = product.id
            val productName = product.getString("name")!!
            val productImage = product.getString("image")!!
            val productPrice = product.getLong("price").toInt()!!
            val hasDiscount = product.getBoolean("hasDiscount")!! // here is my error, I'm assuming that this value is not null, but is null at the database, if I change my pojo with all ? as posible null values I also get the same here
            productList.add(Product(produdctId,productName,productImage,price,hasDiscount))
        }
        return Resource.Success(productList)
    }
```

Now, If I add to my pojo to all atributes the ? operand to say that each value could be null and delete the !! to the getLong, string and so on in my datastore I will not get the default value I have created in my POJO, instead null comes.

So I have a product with
productId, name , image , price but hasCombo could be or not at the database, if that variable is not at the product I want to return false , not null if that variable is not find

### EDIT

Have used the @Exclude attribute to the properties that are not always needed to the product but the problem persists

### EDIT 2

In some product items at Firebase I dont have the field hasDiscount, when I fetch the list of products and one product does not have this field I want to return false instead of null, since in my data class I have false as the default value of the field hasDiscount

If I do this

```
   data class Product(val productId:String = "",val name:String = "", val image:String = "", val price: Int = 0, val hasDiscount:Boolean? = false)
```

and this

```
...
val hasDiscount = product.getBoolean("hasDiscount")
productList.add(Product(produdctId,productName,productImage,price,hasDiscount))
```

null is also returned, and I dont know why since I have explicit said that if hasCombo is not a field in the document, I want to return false instead of null

Comment: add check if snapshot exists snapshot.exist

Comment: that will check if the entire product exists or not, but not if the attribute is null to give it the default value of false, this also makes the same problem

Comment: FYI this doesn't compile: `val price: Int = ""`

Comment: sorry, edited, I had a typo writing the question

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited my question, any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: @CoffeeBreak check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have used a ternary operator, if the value is null, just return the defualt value, so , data class initialization just works to make an empty constructor for Firebase to use `document.toObject(pojo::class.java)`, so , if you want to return a default value for properties that might not be a field of your object in Firebase, do this

```
val hasDiscount = product.getBoolean("hasDiscount")?: false
```

then, if you are not using `toObject()` it does not require to have an empty constructor